# How to fetch values from inputosaurus-text

Tags: jquery

I've found nice element for my project [Jquery Inputosaurus](https://plugins.jquery.com/inputosaurus-text/).

But I haven't found any ways how to fetch values from this element use php or jquery. I assume that should get "hidden element" and find child elements via jquery.
Can anybody show me the right way how to fetch data from this element via jquery or php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see the input-element will remain the same, but will be hidden.

The multiple values you enter into the inputosaurus widget will end up as one single string with the values separated using `,`. The separator for this can be configured using the outputDelimiter option.

Let's take the first example on the page as an example:

`<input type="text" value="support@mysite.com" id="widget1" />`

Then you activate it using inputosauros as you've probably done:

`$('#widget1').inputosaurus({
    width : '350px'
});`

It already has the value `support@mysite.com` in that example. If I add another value, for example *testing*, then the output value in the hidden input element would become `support@mysite.com,testing`. You can even click the *toggle hidden input/markup* link on the page to see the actual value.

### Fetch using jQuery

The value will be set in this same input element, but the multiple values will be comma separated in a string. To get the values using jQuery you would write:

`alert($('#widget1').val())`

### Fetch using PHP

In order to get it from PHP you'll have to set a name attribute on the input element first, or you will not be able to retreive it from PHP:

`<input type="text" value="support@mysite.com" id="widget1" name="widget1" />`

And to fetch it from PHP after sending the form:

`<?php
echo $_REQUEST['widget1'];`